# error [FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists with different options or config (app/duplicate-app).]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I  want to render this 2 firebase. they are diffrent the first is the firebase for the app and firebase of the creator of the app

Why do I get this error?

React Native

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp,} from "firebase/app";
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  doc,
  deleteDoc,
  onSnapshot,
} from 'firebase/firestore'

var  firebaseConfig1 = {
  apiKey: "asdas",
  authDomain: "asdasdasd",
  projectId: "sadsad",
  storageBucket: "asdsadsa",
  messagingSenderId: "sadasd",
  appId: "1:66067574271:asdasda"
};
  
var firebaseConfig2 = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSysaQumXvVddASFASAS9dIk",f
  authDomain: "ASFASFASFASFASFASFASFAseapp.com",
  projectId: "ASFASAAFAF",
  storageBucket: "ASFAFAS",
  messagingSenderId: "31ASASAFASFFSAFAS6A3",
  appId: "ASF3FASFASASFSASFA0AASFAASFFS"
};
  
export var app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig1)
var run = initializeApp(firebaseConfig2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a single web app can connect to multiple Firebase projects, it needs to be able to identify each of them separately. There can be one default, unnamed project/app, and each other one must have a name.

So give one of both of the apps a name:

```
export var app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig1)
var run = initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, 'second')
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [accessing multiple projects in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#web).

Comment: sir Im sorry but im just new at firebase is it posible to give me a full code sir thank you sir but its okay if dont want to sir thank you

Comment: First off: is it clear from my explanation why your code doesn't work? And does it make sense how the change in the code in my answer would address that problem? --- If so, what have you done with that knowledge in your own code? What it the problem you have now?

Comment: sir thank you for your guidance i finally figured it out